# Adding search by location functionality in Android App

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-location

I'm making an **android app** where I want to connect customers to a certain type of retailers,say Vendor X whose shop location may or may not exist on Google Maps(depends on the retailer).

I want the customers to search for Vendor X near to them . I was reading about adding a shop location via Google Business using one's Google account. However, on a large scale it may be difficult for different Vendor X to add their shop on Google Business since they may lack the technical skill to do the same(no matter how simple the process may be ).

Is there any way where I can get hold of their location(and probably make a Google Business profile for them)when Vendor X clicks on the register profile button?

Can this be done without adding Vendor X on google Maps?

I'm new to Android Development and would appreciate some insights.

PS: If these kinds of questions are unacceptable on this platform ,please comment what I should change or whether I should delete this question completely

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? You can checkout [Places Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests). This will return the nearby establishments for the location you have provided. However, for the establishment to be returned by the API, it should be  added to the Google Maps data.

Comment: @smga08 tbh I've dropped this idea as of now. I'm now making use of zipcodes. So whenever customer queries for vendor X , I match them with vendors in their zipcode. I have the zipcodes of both vendor and customer in my firestore database